Two Moons Impacts On Day Length and Solar Eclipse?
(Edit: Ive decided against the idea after a conversation with a friend who knows a lot more about astrophysics, thanks for the help tho :) )
As much as I love making ecosystems on exoplanets, I cant for the life of me understand the math behind.
I'm building an Earth-like planet (1.25x the diameter though less dense proportionally) with a more extreme axial tilt. I know that moons slow the rotation of a planet and create orbital stability, so I wanted to give my planet two moons-- one roughly equivalent to Earths, and one about 2/3 the radius, which orbits closer to the planet.
I know that having two moons should slow the rotation enough that my planet's day length is likely going to be longer than Earth's, but I don't know what math I would need to come up with a definitive number.
Also if my moons had an orbital period of say 30 and 20 days respectively, would that have any impact on the frequency of solar eclipses? That's less important to me but thinking about it is what got me to realize the day length problem.
(Also, im fully aware of the colossal effects two moons will have on tides and plate tectonics, i promise its a feature and not a bug)

If your first moon, being similar to our moon, is orbiting at the same distance, the second moon will be orbiting at 2/3 of that distance, following Kepler's third law stating that for all the bodies orbiting around an attractor $\frac{T^2} {R^3} = const$.
Being 2/3 of the radius in size and orbiting at 2/3 of the distance, its angular size will be be same as the other moon. But because its orbit is faster, any eclipse it will cause will be shorter. If the moons actually produce eclipses depends also on the apparent size of the main star in the sky, and how often do they happen depends on the geometrical parameters of their orbits.
That said, I am not going into exploring whether such a system is long term stable ( I suspect not).
Also note that the moon slowing down its planet rotation:

it's a process that takes billions of years to take place
it's a continuous process, meaning that you can't fix a longer day and that's it, it won't change any more.


Hey thanks! I actually learned my friend knows a lot more about planet building than I do, and given my conversation with him, i think im going to scrap my twin moon idea. Thank you anyway!
